# BroadcastReceiver not firing on notification action click

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to create a simple notification with a button (action) defined to it. I have managed to display it properly and create a PendingIntent for my action. I have also created a BroadcastReceiver which is supposed to be called when my action is clicked. But it's onReceive() method does not get called. I have no idea why. I also registered BroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest.xml

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button notify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notify);

    notify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent dismissIntent = new Intent("action1");
            dismissIntent.setAction("action1");
            PendingIntent action1intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), dismissIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu)
                            .setContentTitle("My notification")
                            .setContentText("Hello World!")
                            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_menu, "action 1", action1intent);

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(MainActivity.this);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
        }
    });

}

public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("log", "Receiving somthn");

        String whichAction = intent.getAction();

        if (whichAction.equals("action1")) {
            MainActivity.makeToast("This is action 1", context);
        }
    }
}


public static void makeToast(String string, Context context) {
    Toast.makeText(context, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.orglce.notification">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver android:name=".MainActivity$Receiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.orglce.notification.BROADCAST" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 7):

First, if you are going to use `.MainActivity$Receiver`, then `Receiver` needs to be a `static` class.

Second, `dismissIntent` is (redundantly) using `action1` as the action string, but the `<intent-filter>` uses `com.example.orglce.notification.BROADCAST`. These do not match. I recommend getting rid of the `<intent-filter>`, getting rid of the `action1`, and using `new Intent(this, Receiver.class)` to create an explicit `Intent` to identify your `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Yes, it worked! Changing to `new Intent(this, Receiver.class)`. Previously I already had `new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)` but it didn't work, it just didn't pop into my mind that I have to associate intent with Receiver.class and not MainActivity.class. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Tx! Note that in Kotlin a nested class is by default static, so it will work as is.

Answer (score 1):

Your manifest has problem.
You add action to your notification intent with this name "action 1"
you should edit your action name in MainActivity like this:

```js
Intent dismissIntent = new Intent("com.example.orglce.action1");
```

Edit your receiver like this:

```html
<receiver android:name=".MainActivity$Receiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.orglce.action1" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Finally edit your if in broadcast receiver like this:

```js
if (whichAction.equals("com.example.orglce.action")) {
            MainActivity.makeToast("This is action 1", context);
        }
```